# UITableViewCell with UIImageView - Incorrect width at first load

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UITableView with the cells contain **customized layers** like **shadows, drawing lines** and **corner radiuses**. I have done the design through Storyboard using Autolayout in IPhone SE view size.

The problem is when first initialize of UITableView it show like this (which is not should be) :

[image: First UITableView show]

However, when scrolling to bottom, it shows as what it should be, like this:

[image: After scrolling]

I have done so many things to make it updated such as:

```
cell?.imageView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
cell?.imageView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
cell?.imageView.setNeedsLayout()
cell?.imageView.layoutIfNeeded()
cell?.imageView.setNeedsDisplay()
cell?.imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

but it doesn't work.

So, any ideas for that to make it as second picture after the first display loaded?

**- Updated -**

Here the `cellForRow` for corresponding tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell: GProjectsFTContentTVCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GProjFTContentHeaderCellID") as! GProjectsFTContentTVCell

        cell.performPopulateData(data: self.contentInfo![indexPath.row])

        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)

        return cell
    }
```

and its cell class:

```
func performPopulateData(data: APIJSON.ProjectList)
{
   let urlFriendlyFileName: String? = data.cover?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
        self.vwGPFTCTVCBannerPanel.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        self.vwGPFTCTVCBannerPanel.dropShadow()
        self.ivGPFTCTVCBannerImage.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 20.0)

        AF.request(urlFriendlyFileName ?? "").responseImage(completionHandler: { response in

            if let image = response.value {
                self.ivGPFTCTVCBannerImage.image = image

            }
        })

        self.lblGPFTCTVCTitle.text = data.title
        self.lblGPFTCTVCTitle.font = FontPredefine.SFProSemiBold(withSize: 16.0)
        self.lblGPFTCTVCTitle.textColor = ColorPredefine.greenTextColor
        self.lblGPFTCTVCSubTitle.text = data.subtitle
        self.lblGPFTCTVCSubTitle.font = FontPredefine.SFProRegular(withSize: 12.0)

}
```

For layout, what I have done is like this:

[image: Layout constraints visual]

[image: Layout constraints values]

Comment: Please share your complete code in `cellForRow`.

Comment: I'd be curious to see what the constraints for you imageView look like. Also, what is the contentMode for your imageViews? Lastly, are all of your images the same size?

Comment: @koen  take a look on updated question

Comment: @rob take a look on visuals i have edited on. contentmode i use is ```AspectFill```

Comment: Not sure if related, but in general you should download and prepare your data *before* populating your cells.

Comment: @user1986121 your constraints look ok. But you should not be calling `reloadRows` in your `cellForRow(at:)` method. Also, I would not recommend making an api call in your cell class. Do that in the view controller. When the api request completes, then you can call `reloadRows` once your have stored your images somewhere. Give that a shot and let us know how it goes.

Comment: One more thing, when you download your images, make sure that you only update the imageView on the main thread. If you don't, often times the UI won't render properly.

Comment: have you tried to populate the image on willDisplay cell delegate method instead? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview

Comment: @Rob yeah! I think I missed on one important thing, to make it loaded into the main thread!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bingo! I have spent hours to fix on this thing, I have been silly as I missed on this important thing, that I simply need to put on this code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    cell?.performPopulateData(data: self.contentInfo![indexPath.row])
}
```

and now it works as what it should be. Thanks to @Rob for give me this idea.

Comment: This may have solved your image problem, but it still is not recommended to download data from within `cellForRow`. Your data should be ready to go and *then* you can update your table.

Comment: @koen i acknowledged that image should be cached first. But for my case, i want to reduce data load time by display the text first and then image will come last. Else, i need to wait image to finish up their work before load the other data and it takes user time to wait.